# #2013 error when starting the dev desktop

Tags: database

My computer (a Mac) froze while I was working on a site, and I had to switch it off by holding onto the on/off button. When I tried restarting the dev desktop, it kept giving the "Process start timeout" error; when I tried accessing the database, I got the following message:

> `#2013` - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61
>   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Do you have any idea on how I can resolve this?

I've found a solution, but now I keep getting this message:

> The specified file temporary://fileJ75lqi could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.

Comment: Seems to be related to a problem with port numbers/bind address of the MySQL server...see [this post](http://drupal.org/node/129982) for a bunch of suggestions for a fix

Comment: Ah, that one's a bit easier :) You need to give your web server user write permissions over the "sites/default/files" folder, e.g. `chmod -R 755 /path/to/root/sites/default/files`.

Comment: sorry to sound ignorant, but how do i do that? Do i do it through admin? and if so where?

Comment: If you don't know how to do it I'd really advise getting someone who does to help you, that's messing about with POSIX permissions and you need to know what you're doing or things can go horribly wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

Your first error seems to be related to a problem with port numbers/bind address of the MySQL server; see [this post](http://drupal.org/node/129982) for a bunch of suggestions for a fix.

The second error is a permissions issue; you need to give your web server user write permissions over the "sites/default/files" folder, for example using the following command:

```bsh
chmod -R 755 /path/to/root/sites/default/files
```

If you don't know how to do it I'd really advise getting someone who does to help you, that's messing about with POSIX permissions and you need to know what you're doing or things can go horribly wrong.